# reason for Close: lack of research?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Introduce a  “general reference” close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason)

I'm deliberately reopening this (see [Should a clear lack of research be grounds for closing a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102811/should-a-clear-lack-of-research-be-grounds-for-closing-a-question) and links from there). Often I want to vote to close a question by a newbie on the grounds that this is basic info that's right there in the docs or easy to find answered (probably on Stackoverflow) by googling, and s/he clearly has done no research whatever. Wouldn't it be good if "lack of research" was one of the radio button options? I request this formally as an option. I do *not* agree that "not a real question" covers this communicatively.

Comment: Oh the irony, as this question is a frequently asked question that appears to not have been well researched.

Answer (score 23):

How about downvoting?

> This question **does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo) [emphasis added]

Just as not all incorrect answers need to be removed, not all stupid questions need to be closed.  Sometimes downvotes are enough.

Comment: I do that too. In closing what I'm aiming to do is remove the question altogether, as it's just adding unnecessarily to the used bandwidth.

Answer (score 10):

Ok, so let's remember what "closing" actually does here:

1. **It prevents new answers from being posted.** Good for questions that can't or shouldn't be answered in their present state.
2. **It nominates them for deletion.**

Now, why would you want to do that to a question without any research? Perhaps because...

- ...It's too broad or vague to be answered effectively without writing a textbook. (**Not a Real Question**)
- ...It's already been answered elsewhere on the site. (**Exact Duplicate**)
- ...It's really just asking for opinions, since the author was too lazy to provide any criteria by which answers could be judged. (**Not Constructive**)
- ...It consists only of a link to the author's website / code dump, since he didn't bother doing even enough debugging to describe the problem with *words*. (**Too Localized**)
- ...It's something you learned 10 years ago, by reading *books* dammit, and got a nasty papercut in the process, what's wrong with these kids thinking they can just ask questions on the Interweb and have folks answer them, the nerve I tells ya! (Yeah, there's no close reason for this one).

So yeah - the best reasons for closing unresearched questions are already covered.

---

Side note: the whole point of these sites is to make the effort folks put in helping others more widely available and useful by forcing it into this (slightly-unnatural) format. As irritating as it can be to see a "lazy" question posted, that really doesn't matter as long as it's a good (reasonably common, constructive) question and it gets a good answer. If it *can't be answered effectively* without a bit more background from the author, that's a solid reason to close it - but otherwise, you might as well suggest a "Don't like the cut of your jib" close reason.