# Adding option to close a question because the answer is easily researched

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, close-reasons

Earlier today I wanted to flag a [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57952/customer-care-vs-customer-service) on **Workplace** because - it seems to me - the answer could be very easily researched. Literally one quick Google search away.

I was unsure which option to choose under **Flag/Should be closed**. The options are:

- **duplicate of ...**
- **off-topic because ...** (I didn't feel it was really off-topic, simply trivial, and a lazy on the part of the person asking it)
- **unclear what you're asking ...**
- **too broad**
- **primarily opinion based**

I didn't really feel that any of these apply, but ended up flagging it as "opinion based", simply because I felt it was a poor question and should be taken down.

**Question 1:** In the future, which option would be best suited to that type of situation?

**Question 2:** Could we edit the definitions of one of these options to include the text "this question is easily researched/trivial" option, or could we add an additional option for that purpose?

**Question 3:** Last but not least, was I actually being a "snob" in thinking that this question should have been closed? Aka, am I in the wrong, vs the person asking that question?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102811/should-a-clear-lack-of-research-be-grounds-for-closing-a-question?

Comment: See also: [Introduce a general reference close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86043)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the appropriate threads, guys.