# Should the SE network become a repository for all possible questions in a given category?

Tags: discussion, scope

So, I may have gotten into a bad (good?) habit of turning to the relevant SE site whenever I have a question - I barely even google things anymore. I've become accustomed to if I have a specific question, SE has a specific answer. Every once in a while I can't find a question on SE, and this rattles my world view a bit. I do some preliminary googling, and usually find it in the first or second link, no harm done. My next instinct at this point, as that this question *should* be on the appropriate SE site, because I asked it, ergo, others will ask it.

I know this has a lot to do with the philosophy of each SE site, but should SE become a list of all possible questions? Is there a minimum "The answer to this question needs to take x amount of minutes to research before you should consider posting it", and more importantly, if you've researched it, found the answer, and found the answer useful, should you post the question and answer it for future SE users, or is the fact that you so easily found an answer an indication that it shouldn't be on the SE network?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102811/should-a-clear-lack-of-research-be-grounds-for-closing-a-question is relevant.

Comment: Do you really want a "how do I turn my computer on?" question on SU?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a bunch of questions in any given topic that simply don't work well on Stack Exchange. See: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Beyond that... There's no particularly good reason to disallow clear, focused, *on-topic* questions. Research is necessary to avoid asking duplicates, but often what trips people up isn't so much the lack of research as it is the lack of clarity; if I had to pick one problem that plagues Stack Exchange sites more than any other, the near-universal inability of folks to work out and communicate what they actually need before clicking "Post Your Question" would be it.

By all means, if you've struggled with a problem and found a solution, write up the question and the answer for others' benefit. Be wary of posting "fake" questions though; if you haven't actually faced the problem yourself (or worked directly with someone who has), you're unlikely to express it in a form that will easily benefit anyone. The Internet is already littered with tutorials and HOWTOs that no one has ever needed, FAQs that no one has ever asked.

#### See also:

- [Should Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general) be awarding "A"s for Effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effor)
- [Should a clear lack of research be grounds for closing a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102811/should-a-clear-lack-of-research-be-grounds-for-closing-a-question)
- [Introduce a  "general reference" close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason)