# On which sites is off-site research strongly encouraged or required, and for what types of questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

My understanding has been that off-site research to find answers to a question before posting is *generally* not required to ask a question on a Stack Exchange site. Searching for duplicate questions *within* the network site one wants to ask on *is* expected, but not doing research off-site (at least- not in general across all network sites). This seems to be represented in FAQs like [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/997587), [How should we deal with Google questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8724/997587)

Are there any sites where an expectation for off-site research is

- culturally custom, but not as a written guideline or rule?
- a written guideline/recommendation according to meta discussion?
- a written rule according to meta discussion?

And if so, for what *kinds* of questions on those sites are such expectations held, and *why*? If you can link to related meta discussion, that would be helpful.

My motivation for this question is similar to my motivation for asking [Is there stigma associated with self-answers on certain network sites? Or different etiquette? If so, why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385418/997587) - I want to get a birds-eye view of expectations across various network sites on a specific issue to be prepared for what will be expected of me if I want to ask questions there.

I plan to follow up on this with a separate question on what general principles are useful for deciding when (if ever) a site should expect research off-site research, and for what types of questions.

Comment: [Useful offsite research](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) 

Comment: Given the timing, I assume you are thinking about someone very specific. In that case imho users aren't mad because of the self answering. They are mad because the user is constantly posting self answered question that have little to no interest and can be easily solved by a Google search....

Comment: Basically: it depends on how much the user looks like they are gaming the system. One question every 6-8 time units? No problem. But I suppose no one would like it if I started posting self answered question like "Is [pokemon] available in Pokemon Scarlet", "Can you be left handed in Pokemon Scarlet", "How many ending has Pokemon Scarlet", "How many save slot does Pokemon Scarlet have", "Can you change your gender later in Pokemon Scarlet"  etc. all the same day

Comment: @SPArcheon what does routine-self-answering have to do with this question?

Comment: Missing research is a downvote reason. Until now I never really thought about what kind of research is meant there.

Comment: @starball like I said, considering the timing of this question I assumed you were talking about a specific *conflict* between users that happened recently that involved serial posting of self answered questions that could be solved by a simple Google search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is in progress. There's a lot of meta discussion to read. You're welcome to help out.

Content can be found from:

- [Stack Exchange search: "`is:q [discussion] research`"](//stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3aq+%5bdiscussion%5d+research)
- [Stack Exchange search: "`is:q [discussion] research google`"](//stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3aq+%5bdiscussion%5d+research+google) (starball went through all of this on Nov 6 2023)
- [Googling "`site:stackexchange.com/help/on-topic "google"`"](//www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackexchange.com%2Fhelp%2Fon-topic+%22google%22) (starball went through all of this on Nov 6 2023)
- [Googling "`site:stackexchange.com/help/on-topic "research"`"](//www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackexchange.com%2Fhelp%2Fon-topic+%22research%22) (starball went through all of this on Nov 6 2023)

Entries are sorted on a semi-best-effort-basis by [site total number of questions](//stackexchange.com/sites#questions)

#### Sites that have such requirements/expectations

- **Salesforce**: [/help/on-topic](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  > While not every question fits this pattern in the same way, a general expectation is that a question post should include [...] The implementation that led to the issue (the code, metadata, or design, in its current form).
  > and/or the research and work you’ve done so far on the issue.
- **English Language & Usage**: [/help/on-topic](//english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  Also [New close reason: include the research](//english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5459/468411)

  > Please **include the [research](//english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5039/468411)** you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our [English Language Learners](//ell.stackexchange.com) site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](//english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573/468411) are off-topic.

  Though see also [Is a question that can be answered by trivial googling a valid question?](//english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10259/468411) and the more recent [Replacing our "research" close reason](//english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15694/468411).
- **English Language Learners**: [/help/on-topic](//ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  Also, quoting the custom close reasons:

  > Basic questions on **spelling, meaning or pronunciation** are off-topic as they should be answered using a dictionary. See: [Policy for questions that are entirely answerable with a dictionary](//ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/466/165353)
  >
  > This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please edit to **add the research** you have done in your efforts to answer the question, or **provide more context**. See: [Details, Please](//ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/165353).
- **Drupal Answers**: [Can I use comments to tell someone that they should have done proper research before asking?](//drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2725/109307). Quoting Apaderno:

  > Drupal Answers should not be the site where users ask Drupal-related questions without first looking for a solution themselves. [...] it is legitimate to ask what in the official documentation was not clear to the OP, since we are not here to duplicate the Drupal.org documentation;

  See also: [How should "RTFM" questions be addressed?](//drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1104/109307)
- **Graphic Design**: For font-identification questions: [What are the requirements for style identification questions?](//graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2930/178122)

  > DO: Tell us what you’ve already attempted
  > A simple search on your favoured search engine will often get you what you want. You can also use reverse image searches to find the source of your image.
  >
  > If none of those give you successful results, let us know which ones you have tried so that we’re not re-tracing steps you may have already taken.
- **German Language** (requires to consult at least one (any) dictionary): ["Research effort" revisited](//german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/698/57234)

  - Also related: [Off Topic - Prior research, why only translation requests?](//german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/647/57234)
  - [Why should somebody consult an online translation service before asking here?](//german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1357/57234)
  - [What kind of questions have to indicate prior research?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/848/57234)
- **History**: [/help/on-topic](//history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  > [Questions are on-topic if they're not] Questions answered by a simple Google search or to be found in a Wikipedia page

  See also [What should be the standard message for "Please document research"?](//history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3674/60097), and [When do we consider a question to be easily answered by "a simple search"?](//history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4018/60097)
- **French Language**: [/help/on-topic](//french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  > *What is the meaning of this word?* We do ask that you look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. If you can't find the answer you're looking for, go ahead and ask, but do provide the context in which you found the word or expression, and tell us why you find the dictionary answer unsatisfactory.
- **Medical Sciences**: [/help/on-topic](//medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  > This site also requires questions to show a reasonable degree of prior research. Your question should, if possible, show what you found in your research that you don't understand or doesn't answer your question.

  See also: [Should 'prior research prerequisite' policy be revisited?](//medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1385/26252) and [What kind of research is expected here before asking questions?](//medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/353/26252). Also, quite confusingly, there is also [Revisiting Research, A reason to close](//medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/515/26252).
- **Latin Language**: [/help/on-topic](//latin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  > On the other hand, questions of the following kinds should generally not be asked here:
  >
  > - translation requests or etymological queries that show no serious research effort using readily available online sources
- **Russian Language**: [/help/on-topic](//russian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  > Can I ask about the meaning of a single word?
  > Like Translation, show research effort. Before posting, check if:
  >
  > - It's in the dictionary;
  > - It's easily found in a Google search.
  >   If the answer to this two points is no, you can ask simple questions like this one.

#### Sites that potentially have such requirements/expectations

- **Ask Different** (though it's not clear to me whether this encompasses off-site research): [New "No Research" close reason?](//apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3030/479746)
- **Travel**:

  - [Should showing zero research be a close-reason?](//travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3985/132615) [answer by mottoDrizzt](//travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4000/132615) says: "*SE network is not a substitute for Google or any other search engine, it's a place to post question that you find hard to solve on your own.*"
  - Reverse image search is not required: [Does not trying reverse image search constitute "lack of research"?](//travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3814/132615)
- **Music: Practice & Theory**:

  - [Should we require prior research?](//music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3404/89547). [One of the mods interprets](//music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3405/89547) the Help Center guidance as requiring off-site research even though they are aware that they may be stretching their interpretation.
  - But then there's also https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2089/89547
- **Linguistics**: [/help/on-topic](//linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  > Also, make sure your question is reasonably scoped, it shows research effort on your part and is not a "do this for me" question.
- **Spanish** (unclear to me exactly what this research must entail): [/help/on-topic](//spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  > Translation of a particular expression or concept to Spanish (but note, you must show your research)
- **Pets**: [What is the minimal amount of research we expect from our users?](//pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/492/25617)
- **Psychology & Neuroscience** (it's unclear to me what the meta consensus is): [What level of initial research is expected on questions?](//psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/66/32417)
- **Hardware Recs**: [/help/on-topic](//hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (unclear whether the "should" is a hard (rule) or soft (guideline) "should") under "Quality Guidelines":

  > Show previous research - Tell us what products you are aware of that do not meet your needs. Otherwise, you may get those products as recommendations, wasting your time and ours.
- **Italian** (though it's not clear to me exactly what the rules and guidelines are): [/help/on-topic](//italian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Should we admit “easily” answerable questions?](//italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21/9624). Quoting the custom close reason:

  > This website is not a translation service: questions that ask to translate a single sentence, without further motivation, are considered off-topic. If you are uncertain about a certain word or nuance of meaning, please edit the question mentioning the exact issue, including your attempts at translation, and describing your doubts.
- **Korean**: [/help/on-topic](//korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

  > Please make your question as clear as possible, with any necessary *context*, *examples and references*, and any *research already done*.

#### Sites that do not* have such requirements*

*(If I'm understanding the meta discussion right, and at least as far as close votes go and not downvotes)

- **Math**:

  - [How to deal with just-google-it questions?](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20108/926489)
  - [What is your opinion on questions when the answer could have been easily found on google?](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12420/926489)
- **Ask Ubuntu**:

  - [How much research effort is expected of Ask Ubuntu users?](//meta.askubuntu.com/q/11923/1624654)
  - [How strict should one be with questions on easily researchable questions?](//meta.askubuntu.com/q/14826/1624654)
  - [How about adding a "Check List" for Every New AU User who asks a Question?](//meta.askubuntu.com/q/2284/1624654)
- **Unix & Linux**: [What do you think about questions for which answers could be trivially Googled?](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5756/550426)
- **Geographic Information Systems**: [/help/on-topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) requests it, but for reasons of quality, and seemingly not as a requirement.

  > please make an initial effort to research the answer before you ask a question. That will help you write a great, focused question that attracts excellent answers.

  See also: [New close reason for when question does not show any research effort?](//gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4915/215576)
- **SharePoint**: [Is it ok to ask easily Google-able questions like "What is 'Feature Stapling'?" here?](//sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/q/607/106368)
- **Science Fiction**: For story identification: [How much research is expected before posting for story-identification?](//scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12536/159649)
- **Role-Playing Games**: [What are the research expectations of questions on RPG Stack Exchange?](//rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11498/79881)
- **Raspberry Pi**: [Should questions covered in the "quick start" guide be off-topic?](//raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14/150634) (not about Google, but a well-known doc)
- **Web Applications**: [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](//webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/305006) (and a lot of other related meta Q&A about related controversy with mod actions)
- **Aviation**: [Should we close questions for not doing research?](//aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1551/67175)
- **Space Exploration**: [Is evidence of research not required?](//space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/605/50267)
- **Christianity**:

  - [Closing a question due to lack of research](//christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6434/60997)
  - [Why not more emphasis on own search?](//christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6298/60997)
- **Literature**:

  - [Should we embrace non-Googlers?](//literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/116/17802)
  - [What kind of research is expected for questions here?](//literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/917/17802)
  - [How much self-research should we be encouraging](//literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1018/17802)
- **DevOps**: [What is the best way to close a question that is fully answerable with a single google search?](//devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/38667). See also [Would it be possible to close questions because of insufficient research effort?](//devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/260/38667)

#### Meta discussions about research in general

- Meta Stack Exchange:

  - [Should a clear lack of research be grounds for closing a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102811/997587) seems to be quite outdated
- Stack Overflow:

  - [Where should I do my research, and are low research effort questions bad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367302/11107541)
  - [What if they COULD google their question in 5 seconds?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371347/11107541)
  - [How do we handle questions that one could have found answer to just by googling?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352599/11107541)
  - [Should a question be flagged for having no research at all?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270946/11107541)
  - [Answering questions that show lack of research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255657/11107541)
  - [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11107541)
  - [Helping users who are unable/unwilling to Google](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270522/11107541)
- Server Fault: https://meta.serverfault.com/q/8144/993961 (seems to be pretty outdated (Ex. discussion on "help vampires"))
- Software Engineering: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6559/414749
- Electrical Engineering:

  - [What qualifies as "research effort"?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5306/326729)
  - [Question closed with "Insufficient preliminary research" cause](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3327/326729)
  - [What's happened to value in research effort?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2666/326729)
- Code Review: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6874/267244
- English Language & Usage: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4943/468411
- English Language Learners: [How much effort is enough effort?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2872/165353)
- Security:

  - [Close reason: lacks basic research](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2006/283712). Top answer is against questions with answers in the top search results of google (unclear if they're talking about answers from Q&A in the Security SE site, but I assume not).
  - [Why do people post questions on here they can easily google an answer for?](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2171/283712)
  - [Are low effort questions off topic?](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3245/283712)
- Arqade / Gaming:

  - https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2704/297372
  - https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6975/297372
- English Language Learners:

  - [An emerging pattern of "research" close votes](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3531/165353)
  - [Policy for Research Effort in Questions, and its Strictness](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/721/165353)
  - [How to handle questions if answers can be found in a grammar book as "basic" knowledge](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4953/165353)
  - [Are 'research/detail' close votes being used too liberally?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5492/165353)
- Politics: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2583/45448. Top answer discusses googling.
- Skeptics:

  - [How about some minimal effort when asking a question?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2444/66816)
  - [How much research do we expect before someone asks a question?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1856/66816)
  - [How to deal with questions which an off-site search can answer?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/71/66816)
- Chemistry: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3234/129302
- Physics:

  - https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8987/351695
  - https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5033/351695
- History: https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/156/60097
- Movies & TV: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4084/98509
- World Building:

  - https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6586/100417
  - https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/443/100417
  - https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7869/100417
  - Also, https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic says under "General Guidelines":

    > Should include research: What ideas have you considered, or what information have you already looked at or failed to find?

    But note "should", whereas all the other items in the list start with "Must".
- Physical Fitness: https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/q/400/39221
- Workplace: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2221/137881
- Parenting: https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/260/43844
- Game Development: https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/799/168600
- Blender: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2676/160331
- Judaism / Mi Yodeda: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3540/32398
- Christianity:

  - https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/848/60997
  - https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1797/60997
- Biblical Hermeneutics: https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/635/53664
- Raspberry Pi: https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/503/150634
- Freelancing: https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/219/28770
- Emacs: https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/178/41312
- Chess: https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/832/33971
- Internet of Things: https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/q/114
- Artificial Intelligence: https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9/64296
- Astronomy: https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/428/48784

Comment: Couldn't this be summarized by "Each stack exchange is a separate community, potentially each having their own guidelines on how much research is needed. check the local meta for the site you're interested in participating in"? Sure, technically you're breaking the sites up into lists based on your own per-site research, but now you're potentially creating a scenario where this answer could easily become out of date or misleading when all one needs to do is research the site they're interested in.

Comment: @KevinB it's not like a site will change its policy often, so chances of the answer becoming wrong or out of date are very small. That said, it requires huge efforts to fill it up with all sites, so if anything should be made CW and make it clear others are welcome to add their own findings.

Answer (score 6):

On Stack Overflow, we are encouraged to embrace the Googlers, and be happy if the question is the number one result for a search. The asker is under no obligation to have Googled their error message before coming and asking. They are of course under an obligation to tell us their error message, and other information that may end up relevant, as the other answers already explain.

But Stack Exchange is more than just Stack Overflow. On [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/), you can't ask any kind of question that pops into your head, even if it's a real problem you face. No question can ask for a diagnosis (what is this funny spot on my toe?) or medical advice, for you or anyone else, and there is an expectation of research before asking. This isn't on the "how to ask" page, because the level of per-site customization to support that wasn't coded, but it's a policy the moderators enforce. Here's [a meta question](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/should-prior-research-prerequisite-policy-be-revisited) about it. (As always when this comes up, Carey Gregory, the moderator on Medical Sciences, is not related to me and we don't particularly interact.) The moderators also expect links in answers and can and do delete answers that are not backed up with citations.

[History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) also has [research requirements](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-my-question-get-a-downvote/785#785) for both questions and answers, as does [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/), where questions must be about a "notable claim" not just something your cousin's neighbour told you.

These are the firmest and most-enforced "research before you ask" policies I've met. Several sites have a "back it up" policy for answers, requiring either citations or an assertion that you have personal experience with the situation. Two that come to mind are [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) and [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: nice. TL;DRs about the rationales would improve this answer.

Comment: I don't know the rationales beyond what we can all read in the meta questions; I'm not part of the meta communities of those sites. Perhaps some others will provide them.

Comment: "This isn't on the "how to ask" page, because the level of per-site customization to support that wasn't coded, but it's a policy the moderators enforce." - Technically, the CMs could customize this (and any other) Help Center page on a per-site basis; it'd just then prevent any updates to the network-wide version from being applied to the site it's been customized on. It's not a code issue, just a matter of the CMs' approach to creating site-specific overrides of Help Center pages (we rarely did so when I was a CM).

Answer (score 5):

If you want a good answer, it's best to explain why "doing the obvious thing" doesn't work.

A question at Chinese.SE might ask:

> What does 你会说汉语吗 mean?

and an answer would be:

> I put this into [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com.hk/?hl=zh-CN&sourceid=cnhp) and it said: *Do you speak Chinese?*

The OP might comment on this answer with "well, I could have done that...".

You see, **if the OP doesn't do the obvious thing, then the answers are going to do the obvious thing**.  Such questions don't help the OP.  Such questions don't help the site.

Now imagine the above question, but scaled to any conceivable sentence in Chinese.  As such, there's a close reason at Chinese.SE:

> Questions **asking for translations** are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service.

Comment: makes sense for that context. "obvious thing" can vary with expertise though. In the questions I answer on Stack Overflow, what's obvious to me that someone should do to figure out the answer themselves is clearly not obvious to the people asking.

Comment: [japanese.se] has the same policy for the same reason.

Comment: *[English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour)* has the (custom) close reason (my emphasis): *"Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered* ***using commonly-available references are off-topic."***

Comment: Spanish Language has a similar close reason "Questions that show no effort are off-topic: translations & definitions easily found online; corrections (homework) posts with no clear question. Tell us what you do understand and we will help you with what you don't. " (I have deleted the Spanish version which follows.)

Answer (score 3):

My feeling is that quick (not exhaustive) off-site research to find answers to a question before posting should be performed prior to asking a question on a Stack Exchange site.

Without that I think the Stack Exchange sites will have many questions posted that can be readily answered elsewhere on the web.

To find out whether a site strongly encourages or requires off-site research, and for what types of questions, I recommend visiting the site, its tour, help center and per-site Meta, rather than relying on a list compiled on this site that can become outdated.

Comment: how do you reconcile that understanding with [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/997587) and [How should we deal with Google questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8724/997587)?

Comment: @starball I think those Q&As are as much or more about "copy/pasting embarrassing links to lmgtfy.com (or similar responses in comments, which aren't downvotable) in an attempt to belittle the questions' authors".  In any event, I've revised my answer because I'd forgotten about them and overlooked them in your question.

Comment: But surely posting on SE *is* research.

Comment: @Chenmunka I think posting on SE is research subsequent to a quick web review akin to but not exhaustive like a literature review prior to scientific research.

Comment: @Chenmunka Please elaborate.

Comment: SE should not be the last resort when trying to solve a problem when all other avenues have failed.  SE should be the *first* port of call.  Forcing users to do spurious searches elsewhere devalues SE as a whole and reduces its effectiveness as a repository of information.

Comment: @Chenmunka Thank you. I agree with the first statement but not with the second and third understanding that you are referring to post a question. However a SO / SE / SE Meta chatroom might be the "*first* port of call".

Comment: (cont.) Depending on each user's circumstances, they might have to look for other options, like creating a digital garden / blog or a specific community where such questions are allowed. Regarding communities, in some circumstances, it might be required to look for a non-SE community as the "*first* port of call"

Answer (score 3):

While the language reflects the culture it was written for, I think ESR's asking questions the smart way describes it as

> When you ask your question, display the fact that you have done these things first; this will help establish that you're not being a lazy sponge and wasting people's time. Better yet, display what you have learned from doing these things. We like answering questions for people who have demonstrated they can learn from the answers.

More precisely - it shows you've *put in* effort into solving the problem, *shared your findings*, and importantly saves folks who read your question time since they don't need to retread your steps and can see where you've gone wrong.

I'd rather put it less as offsite research, but rather *laying the groundwork* for someone else to understand a problem without access to it

It’s worth considering culture - and the balance between the needs of 'those skilled in the arts', 'petty dabblers' like myself and a random person who's just completely confused by an issue and doesn't know where to start.

It’s less about 'offsite research' and more about 'making the effort to help others help you', IMO.