# Find (down-) votes that are contested by others

Tags: discussion, down-votes

**EDIT: Accepting the duplicate based on answers to that question being similar to my suggestion**.

Sometimes after downvoting a post, somebody improves the post. Hence the reason for the downvote may vanish. Still the downvote remains. This is bad in particular if the downvote causes the post to have a negative score.

Is there an easy way to list all the votes a user (oneself) has cast that are contested (other votes opposing mine), along with the current up/down ratio of the post?

Or is there a way to quickly find all posts that I have downvoted which were edited after my downvote?

Currently the "votes" tab on my user page only list what I voted, not the voting status of the object in question.

(Somewhat related:

- [Accepted correction after down-vote will neutralize the down-vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108197/accepted-correction-after-down-vote-will-neutralize-the-down-vote)
- [Suspend Upvoting/Downvoting Within the Answer's First Five Minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33506/suspend-upvoting-downvoting-within-the-answers-first-five-minutes)
- [Is there a way to cancel the downvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85398/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-the-downvote)
- [Downvote "pile-on" on closed questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181187/downvote-pile-on-on-closed-questions)
  )

Comment: I forgot to add a link to [an earlier answer of mine about finding edited downvoted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179911/adding-an-edited-section-to-the-votes-tab/272068#272068).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I rarely downvote (or flag) with**out** leaving a comment to tell the post owner the reason for my downvote (or NAA/VLQ flag), unless the I don't think the post may be improved to a state where I think it doesn't deserve a downvote anymore (like a blatantly trivial homework question on SO). In this way I have opted in to receive notification if the author improves the post and leave a comment telling me it's done. I can then check my notifications and decide whether to retract downvote/flag.

It's always good to explain why you voted a post down or flagged it. Your comment may very effectively help the author out of confusion, especially if they're new to Stack Exchange. Even if it's a templated comment in SEAutoReviewComments it is way more helpful than none. Also note that as [pointed out by Sonic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305605/find-down-votes-that-are-contested-by-others/305609#comment993361_305609), you're prompted to leave a comment for downvoting.

Sometimes I get downvoted without any indication. I would leave a comment on the post, saying sarcastically

> Your downvote without explanation is very helpful :)

Comment: Plus, the system prompts you to leave a comment if you downvote.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks. I've added into my answerrr.

Comment: This requires all the OP to add a comment after a fix was done (by anyone), and for the downvoter to remember his downvote. Do you leave a comment even when a similar comment was there, or do you upvote that comment? If you upvote the comment, does that give you notifications on further comments?

Comment: @tkruse I keave an extra one when I think there's room for improvement regardless of how many atmre there already. I do this on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Not sure the purpose of the sarcastic comment because it will be flagged as "no longer needed" anyway...

Comment: Also generally, I dislike the amount of comments on SO. They get in the way between the question and answers without adding value. They are mostly chit-chat, yet given too much visual space. Deletion does not happen enough. So while functionally comments reduce the problem, I do not consider them a good solution. Possibly if they would be more eagerly hidden / deleted I would dislike them less.